# My django objects get affected when I commit changes in heroku with git

Tags: django, git, heroku

My django admin panel objects get affected when I commit changes in git for my heroku website.
I commit changes to my heroku website from following command in terminal -

```
git add .
git commit -am "make it better"
git push heroku master
enter code here
```

before committing when I add new model:
[image: before committing when I add new model]

after committing changes it disappeared:
[image: after committing changes it disappeared]

Is there any solution for that committing changes does not affect these objects in django admin panel ?

Comment: You seem to be using sqlite? Just add your database file to gitignore then. (Although I would advise you to use a proper database considering you have hosted the website)

Comment: This may be happening because you are resetting your db data on production every time you deploy to Heroku.